# How to get the file format via Idapython?

Tags: ida, idapython, idapro-sdk

I am working on a reverse engineering project on android apk. I would like to check if the file being analyzed is a binary file such as .so file or elf file.  Is it possible to get it from idapro?

[image]

Comment: I copied the wrong function name by mistake, please see edited answer for the correct name.

Answer (score 3):

There is an IDApython function that provides what you're after.

It's called `idaapi.get_file_type_name()` and it will return the same string displayed in the "Load a new file" dialog:

[image: get_basic_file_type]

Additionally, there's another function called `get_loader_name`, which is only accessible through IDA's C SDK and isn't exposed by IDAPython because it wasn't thought to be needed. Emailing hexrays asking it to be included in idapython will probably get a positive response, making it available to future versions.